# How to prove $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}} = \sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}$?

Tags: proof-explanation

My daughter is learning how to rationalise surds for her school exams.  One example being worked through is the following:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{6} + \sqrt{5}}$

In the tutorials she is following, the first step is rearranging to arrive at:

$\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{5}$

She doesn't know the reason for this first step - can hasn't been able to find anything to suggest why it works.

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{6} + \sqrt{5}} \to \sqrt{6} - \sqrt{5}$

Is this just something that just needs to be remembered? She doesn't like to do something without knowing why, hence posting this question.

Comment: It can't, as it is not true in general.

Comment: Note that the equality would imply $1=(\sqrt a - \sqrt b)(\sqrt a +\sqrt b)=a-b$ but it is not always true that $a-b=1$.

Comment: Even better, for $a=b$ we would obtain $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}} = 0$ for all $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Joe Indeed, the usual homework is exactly what you said. Unfortunately the OP copied it wrongly.

Comment: $\sqrt{4}-\sqrt{1}=1 \neq \frac13$

Comment: @AnotherUser $\sqrt{4}-\sqrt{1}=1$, but this is neither equal to $\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general,
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}=\frac{\sqrt a-\sqrt b}{(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)(\sqrt a-\sqrt b)}=\frac{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}{(\sqrt a)^2-(\sqrt b)^2}=\frac{\sqrt a-\sqrt b}{a-b} \tag{*}\label{*} \, ,
$$
using the difference of two squares (since $(x+y)(x-y)=x^2-y^2$, we know that $(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)(\sqrt a-\sqrt b)=(\sqrt a)^2-(\sqrt{b})^2$). In the case $a=6,b=5$, we see that
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{5}}\stackrel{\eqref{*}}{=}\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5}}{6-5}=\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5}}{1}=\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5} \, .
$$
For a school student, it might be clearer if we derive this result directly:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{5}} &= \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5}}{(\sqrt6+\sqrt5)(\sqrt6-\sqrt5)} \\[5pt]
&= \frac{\sqrt6-\sqrt5}{(\sqrt6)^2-(\sqrt5)^2}\\[5pt]
&= \frac{\sqrt6-\sqrt5}{6-5} \\[5pt]
&= \frac{\sqrt6-\sqrt5}{1} \\[5pt]
&= \sqrt6-\sqrt5 \, .
\end{align}
Finally, consider that the equality
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt6+\sqrt5}=\sqrt6-\sqrt5
$$
is equivalent to
$$
1=(\sqrt6+\sqrt5)(\sqrt6-\sqrt5) \, .
$$
(In general, $\frac{a}{b}=c$ *means* $a=b \times c$.) This gives us a straightforward of checking that the result is indeed correct.

Answer (score 3):

Alright. I understand your question now, so please make sure to post 'full' questions like the one you posted later (otherwise it may get downvoted).

Now, here we are doing the following; We have the fraction;
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{5}}
\end{align*}
We can multiply both the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5}$ to get;
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{5}}
&=\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5}}{\left(\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{5}\right)\left(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{6}\cdot \sqrt{6}-\sqrt{30}+\sqrt{30}-\sqrt{5}\cdot \sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5}}{6-5}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5}}{1}\\
&=\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5}.
\end{align*}

So we are done. However, in general, we have;
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}
&=\frac{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}{\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\right)\left(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}\cdot \sqrt{a}-\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ab}-\sqrt{b}\cdot \sqrt{b}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}{a-b}.
\end{align*}

So in general it is;
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}
&=\frac{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}{a-b}.
\end{align*}